# Search in all google spreadsheet pages

Tags: google-sheets

I have google spreadsheet with several pages. Is it possible somehow do search in all pages? How? CTRL+F does search only in current visible page.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

There you can select to search all sheets:

[image]